# Symantec netbackup 8.1

Tags: backup

There was one problem, we use the system for backup of symantec netbackup version 8.1.1
There is a task to reinstall the master server and restore all data. I created a catalog policy, everything worked out with a Bang, the system was demolished and re-installed, the directory was restored successfully, but, the media server and all clients can not connect to the new master, the error "The vnetd proxy encountered an error"

What could be the problem?

`screenshots:`

```
ibb.co/GCNgd2q
ibb.co/V9Gp3QL
ibb.co/dLZhxHZ
```

Comment: could you post some working code or screenshots?

Comment: https://ibb.co/GCNgd2q
https://ibb.co/V9Gp3QL
https://ibb.co/dLZhxHZ

Comment: please [edit] the question to add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Check connectivity over pbx.
You can do that with `bptestconn -v {hostname}`.

Ensure pbx is running. Verify with `bpps -x`.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on your answer to help future users.